# Turn JSON objects with multiple properties into html-elements

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'd like to construct html-elements from JSON-objects with multiple properties. My JSON-file looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "shape1": {
      "fill": "red",
      "stroke": "black",
      "attr": {
        "stroke-width": 5,
        "color": "#000"
      }
    }
  },

  {
    "shape2": {
      "fill": "blue",
      "stroke": "black",
      "attr": {
        "stroke-width": 3,
        "color": "#d19930"
      }
    }
  },

  {
    "shape3": {
      "fill": "green",
      "stroke": "black",
      "attr": {
        "stroke-width": 7,
        "color": "#ffeb00"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I'd like to be able to turn each of these into an element, such as this:

```
<div data-fill:"green" data-stroke="black" data-stroke-width="5" data-color="#000"></div>
```

I'm stuck trying to get access to the properties of the objects. I'm fetching the objects like so:

```
$.getJSON( "/assets/svg-data/svg-forms1.json", function( data ) {
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    // What to do now?
  })
});
```

When console log the objects, I can see that they have been fetched, but how do I now access the contents of the objects and use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the objects have different keys, and you're not interested in the key, you can use `Object.values(value)[0]` to get the contained object that has the properties you want.

```
$.getJSON( "/assets/svg-data/svg-forms1.json", function( data ) {
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    var obj = Object.values(value)[0];
    var div = $("<div>", {
        data: {
            fill: obj.fill,
            stroke: obj.stroke,
            "stroke-width": obj.attr["stroke-width"],
            color: obj.attr.color
        }
    };
    $("#container").append(div);
  })
});
```

Comment: This answer helped me already to understand the basic concept of reaching the values inside the objects. But this only fetches the first object in my JSON-file. How do I fetch all of them(no matter how many there are in the fiel)?

Comment: It should do all of them because of `$.each()`.

Comment: you're right, never mind, I made a mistake when adding more objects to the JSON-file. Everything works fine, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Due to the complex nature of your data, you may need to iterate more than once. Here is a basic example.

```js
var shapes = [{
    "shape1": {
      "fill": "red",
      "stroke": "black",
      "attr": {
        "stroke-width": 5,
        "color": "#000"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "shape2": {
      "fill": "blue",
      "stroke": "black",
      "attr": {
        "stroke-width": 3,
        "color": "#d19930"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "shape3": {
      "fill": "green",
      "stroke": "black",
      "attr": {
        "stroke-width": 7,
        "color": "#ffeb00"
      }
    }
  }
];

$(function() {
  function makeShape(a) {
    var d = $("<div>");
    $.each(a, function(key, val) {
      d.attr({
        "data-fill": val.fill,
        "data-stroke": val.stroke,
        "data-stroke-width": val.attr['stroke-width'],
        "data-color": val.attr.color
      });
    });
    return d;
  }

  $.each(shapes, function(i, v) {
    var s = makeShape(v);
    s.appendTo($(".shapes"));
  });
});
```

```css
.shapes {
  background: #ccc;
}

.shapes div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shapes"></div>
```

As you can see, we iterate the Array, this gives us a number of Objects. Each of these Objects contains more Objects. Example:

```
shapes[0].shapes1.fill
```

This would have a value of "red".

If you can adjust the Data being sent back, I would advise a different structure. Like so:

```
[
  {
    "id": "shape1",
    "fill": "red",
    "stroke": "black",
    "attr": {
      "stroke-width": 5,
      "color": "#000"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "shape2",
    "fill": "blue",
    "stroke": "black",
    "attr": {
      "stroke-width": 3,
      "color": "#d19930"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "shape3",
    "fill": "green",
    "stroke": "black",
    "attr": {
      "stroke-width": 7,
      "color": "#ffeb00"
    }
  }
]
```

This will make iterating the data a lot easier.

```
shapes[0].fill
```

Now you just have to iterate the Array alone.